# Qt Creator (4.2.2) unique pointers navigation in editor

Tags: c++, qt

Qt Creator (4.2.2) features such as "Follow symbol under cursor", "Refactor", "Find Usages", etc are not working for me specifically for unique pointers. These IDE features are enough working for shared pointers. Furthermore, auto completion of methods on unique pointers is also working.

I'm on Windows 10, with Desktop QT 5.8.0 MSVC2015 32bits as kit. I have the ClangCodeModel plugin installed and enabled.

Comment: Some times it works and some times it doesn't. It depends on the depth of the objects pointed to. I gave up on it and when it doesn't work I just write a new temp pointer and copy the member name from it.

Answer (score 1):

The current code model in Qt Creator does not handle templates too well. We are working on the issue by integrating a new code model based on clang, which does handle that properly. Unfortunately it is also significantly slower and progress on this front is slow:-/

I hope we will see significant progress in the next one or two releases.